# Java Try and Catch IOException must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java, try-catch, ioexception

I am trying to use a bit of code I found at the bottom of [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453018/number-of-lines-in-a-file-in-java).  Here is the code in a class that I created for it:

```
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LineCounter {
  public static int countLines(String filename) throws IOException {
    LineNumberReader reader  = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(filename));
    int cnt = 0;
    String lineRead = "";
    while ((lineRead = reader.readLine()) != null) {}
    cnt = reader.getLineNumber();
    reader.close();
    return cnt;
  }
}
```

**My objective is to count the lines of a text file, store that number as an integer, then use that integer in my main class.**  In my main class I tried a few different ways of making this happen, but (being a new programmer) I am missing something.  Here is the first thing I tried:

```
String sFileName = "MyTextFile.txt";
private int lineCount = LineCounter.countLines(sFileName);
```

With this attempt I get the error "unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown."  I don't understand why I am getting this because as I can see the exception is declared in my "countLines" method.  I tried to use a try catch block right under that last bit of code I posted, but that didn't work either (I don't think I did it right though).  Here is my try catch attempt:

```
String sFileName = "MyTextFile.txt";
private int lineCount;{
    try{
        LineCounter.countLines(sFileName);
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println (ex.toString());
        System.out.println("Could not find file " + sFileName);
    }
}
```

Please show me the way!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Initializer block is just like any bits of code; it's not "attached" to any field/method preceding it. To assign values to fields, you have to explicitly use the field as the lhs of an assignment statement.

```
private int lineCount; {
    try{
        lineCount = LineCounter.countLines(sFileName);
        /*^^^^^^^*/
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println (ex.toString());
        System.out.println("Could not find file " + sFileName);
    }
}
```

Also, your `countLines` can be made simpler:

```
  public static int countLines(String filename) throws IOException {
    LineNumberReader reader  = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(filename));
    while (reader.readLine() != null) {}
    reader.close();
    return reader.getLineNumber();
  }
```

Based on my test, it looks like you can `getLineNumber()` after `close()`.

Comment: The answer is technically correct (the OP simply forgot to assign the value to the reference), but that was not a **static** initializer block. It's just an initializer block :)

Comment: Your first bit of code works perfect!  I was so close :)  Your second bit of code works too, but NetBeans tells me the while loop is empty.  The program still compiles and runs ok, so I guess that is acceptable?

Comment: It's simply ignoring the content. You're actually only interested in the amount of lines. You can alternatively also use `BufferedReader` in combination with `int count` which you increment inside the loop.

Comment: I changed the `countLines` again to be more similar to what you had before.

Answer (score 1):

Your `countLines(String filename)` method throws IOException.

You can't use it in a member declaration. You'll need to perform the operation in a `main(String[] args)` method.

Your `main(String[] args)` method will get the IOException thrown to it by countLines and it will need to handle or declare it.

Try this to just throw the IOException from main

```
public class MyClass {
  private int lineCount;
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    lineCount = LineCounter.countLines(sFileName);
  }
}
```

or this to handle it and wrap it in an unchecked IllegalArgumentException:

```
public class MyClass {
  private int lineCount;
  private String sFileName  = "myfile";
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
      lineCount = LineCounter.countLines(sFileName);
     } catch (IOException e) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to load " + sFileName, e);
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the the IOException is because you are not catching the IOException of your countLines method.  You'll want to do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int lines = 0;  

  // TODO - Need to get the filename to populate sFileName.  Could
  // come from the command line arguments.

   try {
       lines = LineCounter.countLines(sFileName);
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println (ex.toString());
        System.out.println("Could not find file " + sFileName);
    }

   if(lines > 0) {
     // Do rest of program.
   }
}
```