# Java scanner count lines in file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a question, I tried to create an app that counts all occurences of a symbol in a file... The scanner method "nextLine" stops at an empty line... Is there a way to keep it going until it reaches the real end of the file?

In short: can I get the REAL number of lines in a file?

Thankyou in advance!

Comment: It doesn't stop until you reach the end of the file. Can you show us code to reproduce this?

Comment: I believe I have the same dilemma. If that's so, the issue is that if the last line is blank, the counter will not count that last line and give a line count one less than actual.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a loop:

```
int count = 0;
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    count++;
    scanner.nextLine();
}
```

`count` will contain number of lines.

Comment: don't forget to use scanner.nextLine(); or you will have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

So I've been doing some research about this problem.  I've been coming up against it recently while writing a line counting program in Java for the class I'm taking.

The reason the [scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class does this is because scanner.next() and scanner.nextLine() return tokens, which are separated by delimiters.  By default the delimiter is [whitespace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29).  So what's happening is that when you call scanner.hasNext() or scanner.hasNextLine() is that it looks to see if there is a token after the next delimiter.  When a file ends in a newline character, there is no token after that, so hasNext() and hasNextLine() return false.

As far as I can tell, to do what you want you'd need to count the number of delimiters, which is better handled in Martinus's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/453067/2134245).  See also AFinkelstein's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14411695/2134245).

Answer (score 0):

See [Scanner.hasNextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29), you should probably use that in the loop condition. There is also a [Scanner.hasNext()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29) if it works better for your needs.