# How do you determine size of string array java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

How do i read a file and determine the # of array elements without having to look at the text file itself?

```
String temp = fileScan.toString();
String[] tokens = temp.split("[\n]+");
// numArrayElements = ?
```

Comment: Do you mean `tokens.length` ?

Comment: Almost duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453018/number-of-lines-in-a-file-in-java . This has been answered and more effectively.

Comment: Unlike C/C++, in Java you can always determine the size of an array using `length`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `length` property of the array:

```
int numArrayElements = tokens.length;
```

Answer (score 2):

The proper expression is `tokens.length`. So, you can assign `numArrayElements` like this:

```
int numArrayElements = tokens.length;
```

This counts the number of elements in the `tokens` array. You can count the number of elements in any array in the same way.

Comment: Minor detail:  `length` does not "count" the number of elements in the array.  Rather, it returns the array size which was stored in the array header when the array object was created (and which cannot have changed since).