# Number of newline characters

Tags: java

I am designing a Utility that counts the words and Number of newline characters.

I have done count task but i dont know how to **count number of new line charcaters in file**.

**Code:**

```
System.out.println ("Counting Words"); 

InputStream stream = Run.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.txt");
InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(stream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (r);     
String line = br.readLine();
int count = 0;

while (line != null) {
    String []parts = line.split(" ");
    for( String w : parts){
        count++;        
    }
    line = br.readLine();
}

System.out.println(count);
```

**test**

This is simple file reading by Java Program

Comment: Just count, how many lines you have read.

Comment: What's wrong with `count`? It seems to be keeping a count of lines.

Comment: i want to read new line character like '\n'....

Answer (score 1):

Just look inside the words:

```
for (char c : w.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == '\n') {
        numNewLineChars++;
    }
}
```

Which goes inside the for loop you already have.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println ("Counting Words");       
InputStream stream = Run.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.txt");
InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(stream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (r);     
String line = br.readLine();
int word_count = 0;
int line_count = 0;

while (line != null) {
    String[] parts = line.split(" ");
    word_count += parts.length;
    line_count++;
    line = br.readLine();
}

System.out.println("Word count: " + word_count + " Line count: " + line_count);
```

Answer (score 0):

It maybe a better option here to use the [LineNumberReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html) class for counting and reading the lines of text. Although this isn't the most efficient way for counting lines in a file (according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453018/number-of-lines-in-a-file-in-java/4425569)) it should suffice for most applications.

From [LineNumberReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html) for readLine method:

> Read a line of text. Whenever a line terminator is read the current line number is incremented. *(A line terminator is usually a newline character '\n' or a carriage return '\r').*

This means that when you call the getLineNumber method of the LineNumberReader class, it will return the current line number that has been incremented by the readLine method.

I have included comments in the code below explaining it.

```
    System.out.println ("Counting ...");       
    InputStream stream = ParseTextFile.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.txt");
    InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(stream);

    /*
     * using a LineNumberReader allows you to get the current 
     * line number once the end of the file has been reached,
     * without having to increment your original 'count' variable.
     */
    LineNumberReader br = new LineNumberReader(r);

    String line = br.readLine();

    // use a long in case you use a large text file
    long wordCount = 0;

    while (line != null) {
        String[] parts = line.split(" ");
        wordCount+= parts.length;
        line = br.readLine();
    }

    /* get the current line number; will be the last line 
     * due to the above loop going to the end of the file.
     */
    int lineCount = br.getLineNumber();

    System.out.println("words: " + wordCount + " lines: " + lineCount);
```