# Why is BufferedReader reading more lines than detected by wc command for large files?

Tags: java, linux, bufferedreader

Here's my Java code that detects the number of lines in a file -

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class CountLinesInFile {

    public static int countLines(String filename) throws Exception{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(filename));
        int count = 0;
        String line = null; 

        do {
            line = br.readLine();
            count++;
        }
        while (line!=null);

        count--;
        br.close();

        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String filename;
        //filename = "catalina6MB";
        //filename = "catalina14MB";
        filename = "catalina327MB";

        int count = countLines(filename);       
        System.out.println("count = "+count);
    }
}
```

The code gives the same result as the `wc -l` command when I use smaller file sizes like 6MB or 14MB. But when I use a larger file (327MB), the code reports a slight greater number of lines -

Output of Java program-

```
count = 4020049
```

Output of wc command-

```
$ wc -l catalina327MB 
4020042 catalina327MB
```

Why is this happening?

**UPDATE**:

I tried it on [this](http://textfiles.com/computers/vendlist.txt) file available online.

Output of Java program-

```
count = 51229
```

Output of wc command-

```
$ wc -l vendlist.txt 
51228 vendlist.txt
```

**UPDATE2:**

Also tried it on [this](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20140402/enwiki-20140402-stub-meta-current18.xml.gz) larger file.

Output of Java program-

```
count = 20520212
```

Output of wc command-

```
$ wc -l enwiki-20140402-stub-meta-current18.xml 
20520206 enwiki-20140402-stub-meta-current18.xml
```

Comment: How do you generate the 327MB file? Is it possible that Java and wc are detecting line breaks differently (\r\n vs. \n), and that this happens 7 times in your large file? (Looking at your code, it doesn't look like the size of the data file is a problem)

Comment: @David it's a tomcat log file.

Comment: I've seen some differences in detecting new lines between software when some files have two carriage returns then a new line versus just 1 and 1, perhaps that is it, perhaps check if you have 7 instances of two carriage returns in a row.

Comment: It's a bit odd to put in a final count-- just because you used a do-while loop where you should have used a while loop.

Answer (score 1):

`sed '$=' vendlist.txt` produces 51229 (one extra line), whereas `wc -l vendlist.txt` produces the 51228. `perl -lne 'END { print $. }' vendlist.txt` produces the counter of **51229**. `cat -n vendlist.txt` produces **51229**. ***There is an extra newline at the end.***

When I tried your code, I got **51229** using vendlist.txt. When using the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/453067/2591612), I got **51228**. Depending on the file and the program, it may or may not discard empty newlines or carriage returns at the end of the file. As shown in the various programs I tried, all treat newlines and carriage returns differently it seems (at least when at the end of the file). I didn't download any of your other test files.