# Built-in method to count number of lines in a CSV file?

Tags: java, csv

> user
>  u1
>  Khulbe
>  Sharma
>  gupta

These are the entries in the CSV file i want to know if there is a Java inbuilt function that can directly give me the number of lines in CSV file? In this case, it would be 5 lines.

Comment: Probably your best bet is to read the file and count the number of newline chars

Comment: You can find several solutions there ; http://stackoverflow.com/q/453018/1140748

Comment: @Micheal Yea I have done that olready,i am new to java so thinking may be there could be a function also like we have count in case of PHP.

Comment: what if the CSV has a header line?

Answer (score 4):

A built-in functionality would be to open the file and read how many lines there are. In Java8 for example, it would look like this:

```
final Path path = Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("your.csv").toURI());
return Files.lines(path).skip(1L).count(); // skip(1L) to ignore the titles
```

Answer (score 2):

CSV has nothing to do with it. All you need is a line count. This can be accomplished in two lines of code with a `LineNumberReader`:

```
lineNumberReader.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
int lines = lineNumberReader.getLineNumber();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Super CSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_reading.html). Have a close look at Example CSV file and the output.

You can put a variable to keep count while using [Super CSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_reading.html) to find the number of lines. Only thing you have to do is to add the jar to your classpath and then access its methods