# why does my while loop run to infinity?

Tags: java, file, loops, while-loop

Why does my loop run to infinity instead of stopping at some point even though when there is finite(10) number of lines in my text file.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class numberOfLines{
    public static void main(String[] args){
       try{
          Scanner cs=new Scanner(new File("poem.txt"));
          int i=0;
          while(cs.hasNextLine()){
             System.out.println(i);
           }
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
          System.out.print("File not found");
          } 
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help on this problem.

Comment: You never actually read the next line, so the `Scanner` stays on line 0 and returns `true`.

Comment: By the way, this is how you count the [number of lines in a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453018/number-of-lines-in-a-file-in-java)

Comment: If you never move forward, the answer to *"Are we there yet?"* will never change.

Answer (score 2):

Because  you never call  `cs.nextLine()`. That means you never consume the value which is in the Scanner. So `ca.hasNextLine()` ever return true;

Comment: @cricket_007 because i is never incremented

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something like `cs.nextLine()` to actually read a line, otherwise there's always a line left since you are never advancing through the file contents.