# How to check line number in .csv using java , readLine() take time in 500 record

Tags: java

I have .csv file and its limit is 500, I used readLine() its take time to check Number of record is 500 or exceeds limit.

Comment: I do not completely understand. You want to check if a csv file has more than 500 records (lines)?

Comment: yes more than 500 not acceptable for process,

Comment: i just upload .csv file its have 500 record and limit of record is 500 so how to check if record is more than 500 without readLine() bcz its take to much time

Comment: it takes time to read 500 lines of a file ?? Anyway, you have not the choice, you have to read the content of the file. With a buffer,  it is rather efficient : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453018/number-of-lines-in-a-file-in-java

Answer (score 1):

there is no chance to access the 500th line directly you need to loop all lines before

```
        public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String FILENAME="path";
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));
        String input;
        int count = 0;
        while((input = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            count++;
        }

        System.out.println("Count : "+count-1); // if you have header 
    }
```