# Read several files at the same time Java

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader, filereader

I would like to read several files at the same time in Java. 
I have for example 5 files, and each file has 50 lines (but I cann't know it in advance).

I would like to read the line number 1 on each file, then the line number 2 on each file etc..

How can I do it ?

I have a BufferedReader array like :

```
BufferedReader[] readers = new BufferedReader[x];
```

Comment: You could use 5 threads. But if you do that to speed things up, all 5 files should be on different drives otherwise it's probably gonna be slower instead of faster.

Comment: I don't want to use threads.. Is it not possible to do this with for and while loops ?

Comment: Why do you need to read them at the same time? And how fast do you need to read them?

Comment: Fill your array with reader responsible for each file, then iterate over them and make them read one line. Repeat until there is no more lines to read.

Comment: @SpiderPig, I need to concatenate information of each file at the same line. The speed is not important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a loop to iterate while you get a new line from the readers.
Inside the loop, add a nested loop to iterate over the readers. In this way, you can read the line matching to the same line number of each `BufferedReader`.

Here is the idea :

```
BufferedReader[] readers = new BufferedReader[5]; 
readers[0] = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("...));
...
readers[4] = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("...));


boolean noMoreLine = false;
while (!noMoreLine)       

   for (BufferedReader reader : readers){
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if (line == null){
           noMoreLine = true;
           System.out.println("no more line");
           break;
        }
        System.out.println("Line " + i + " = line);
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: But how do I know when to stop if I don't know the number of line ? (10 in your example)

Comment: You check  `line` value after `readLine()`. I was updated the code .

Comment: Yes it is ok. I will try this !

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have an array set up, with one buffered reader for each file you need to read. If you want to read the first line of every file, the the second of every file, etc., you need to stop when you've reached the last line of the longest file.

You can get this value by finding the number of lines in each file, and saving the maximum. [Number of lines in a file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453018/number-of-lines-in-a-file-in-java) might be useful.

Then, write a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < longestFileLength; i++) {
    String fileLine1 = readers[1].readLine();
    String fileLine2 = readers[2].readLine();
    //...
    String fileLine99 = readers[99].readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an ArrayList rather than an array.

```
ArrayList<BufferedReader> readers = new ArrayList<>();
...
while(!readers.isEmpty()) {
  for(BufferedReader reader: readers) {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    if(line == null) {
      readers.remove(reader);
    } else {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this solution seems good. I will try it !

Comment: You shouldn't modify collection if you are iterating over it using enhanced for loop. Use `Iterator#remove` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could use streams:

```
while(Arrays.stream(readers).filter(br -> br.ready()).count()>0)
    Arrays.stream(readers).map(br -> br.readLine()).toArray()
```