# How to get the number of lines from a text file in java ignoring blank lines?

Tags: java

At the moment to count the number of lines from a text file I'm using :

```
File f = new File("lorem.txt");
if(f.exists()){
        try {
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));

            while((s = bf.readLine())!=null) {
                if(s.length() > 0) {
                    nbLinesTotal++;
                }
            }
            bf.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
}
```

But I discovered this in java 8 :

```
long count = Files.lines(Paths.get("lorem.txt")).count();
```

which is way faster and better than my loop. But it doesn't ignore blank lines. So, How can I ignore blank lines with this way to do ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of lines in a file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453018/number-of-lines-in-a-file-in-java)

Comment: trim the line before getting length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Files.lines` returns a `Stream<String>`.  You can therefore use the same filtering operations as you can on any other stream:

```
long count = Files.lines(Paths.get("lorem.txt")).filter(line -> line.length() > 0).count();
```